# Troubleshooting a PluginNotFoundException exception

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 8 site on 8.8.6. I installed and tried to use the [fancy_file_delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/fancy_file_delete) module version 2.0.1, however, in trying to load one of its views, `/admin/config/content/fancy_file_delete/list`, I got the exception

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "default_image" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).
```

(I'm including the full stack trace at the bottom of this question).

I grepped in our site's configuration directory, and found that the the string `default_image` seems to be a key for the default image settings for image files. I found this in the storage of several file fields:

```
field.storage.user.user_picture.yml:17:  default_image:

 15 settings:
 16   uri_scheme: public
 17   default_image:
 18     uuid: null
 19     alt: ''
 20     title: ''
 21     width: null
 22     height: null
 23   target_type: file
 24   display_field: false
 25   display_default: false
```

So this doesn't seem to be the missing plugin causing the exception to be thrown. We have images on all of our content types, and we aren't getting exception thrown when they load.

I looked through the git log for our config directory and didn't find deleted file that had `default_image` in the name. So it doesn't appear that we had something in configuration that we deleted later on. If the deletion of this entity was the result of an action that I or another developer of our site did at one point, I don't recall and am not aware of it.

I googled the string of the exception message, and found a couple hits. However, none of them led me to be able to fix the exception. [This issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/2980557) remains an open issue on the entity browser module. [This patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/simple_menu_icons-2801171-9.patch) for the simple_menu_icons module provides a fix for the same exception,  but the code replaces a `File::load()`, which I only find in the `src/FancyFileDeleteBatch.php`. I commented out lines 125-162 of `src/FancyFileDeleteBatch.php`, but that doesn't prevent the exeption from being thrown. Which makes sense-- it's the code for batch deletion, and I'm only trying to load the view.

How can I troubleshoot this exception? Is this an entry for a missing entity, that I can just delete? Or does the code of the module need to be rewritten?

---

What follows is the exception that I get and its full stack trace:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "default_image" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 150 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('default_image', 'storage') (Line: 208)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage('default_image') (Line: 139)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityLabel->preRender(Array) (Line: 1503)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render() (Line: 183)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page->execute() (Line: 1630)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('page_1', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 100)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. Support for this callback implementation is deprecated in 8.8.0 and will be removed in Drupal 9.0.0. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'silenced_deprecation', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 781)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 372)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the module maintainer for Fancy File Delete.  I fixed the issue in 2.0.3. If you want to update it, you should be good.  Make sure to run drush updb and cex after to fix the issue with the config that was causing this.